# Whats wrong with this sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to php and sql , so could you please help me by telling me how to fix this sql error.
The sql is below.

```sql
INSERT INTO xml-group (id,groupid,name,descriptor,cust_id) 
VALUES (1,1,'other contacts','other contacts',16)
```

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '-group (id,groupid,name,descriptor,cust_id) VALUES
>   ('0','0','mobiles','mobile',1' at line 1

Many thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-group (id,groupid,name,descriptor,cust_id) VALUES ('0','0','mobiles','mobile',1' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"-" Hyphen is not allowed in SQL syntax.
use backticks (`) symbol to escape it.

Answer (score 5):

The `-` isn't allowed in an unquoted table name. Use backticks to quote `xml-group`:

```
INSERT INTO `xml-group` (id,groupid,name,descriptor,cust_id) 
VALUES (1,1,'other contacts','other contacts',16)
```

Btw, in a well designed database schema you might avoid such names and use `_` instead.

Comment: check this as an accepted answer if it works for you @JonJames

Answer (score 2):

use backticks arround table name it causes GROUP a special keyword of mysql

```
INSERT INTO `xml-group` (id,groupid,name,descriptor,cust_id) 
VALUES (1,1,'other contacts','other contacts',16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if field ID is an auto-number field, primary index and "1" is already assigned, you'll get an error. (Same with any other fields that require unique values...)

Answer (score 0):

Two options to fix it:

- Replace xml-group with xml_group
- Include backticks around it such as `xml-group`

Personally I would do both of those above options, but you can get away with just one.

You are best to enforce the use of back ticks for a few reasons. The primary reason I use back ticks myself is:

- You do not have to worry about clashing with reserved or future key words.

Other reasons, but often dependant on personal preference and coding standards you have/can enforce on the whole code base are:

- You can easily search the entire project for the use of that specific table. If for example you did `SELECT user FROM users` there is a good chance you have method names, variables, comments etc all containing the word "user" making it hard to find all the queries containing a reference to the user table amongst so many false positives. However, if you enforce the use of back ticks you just have to search for `users` to find all queries referencing it along with fields (as long as you haven't abstract the queries to the point where they are built up at runtime like: "SELECT `$field` FROM `$table`").
- It can help with clarity and readability as it visually separates keywords from variable values like field names and table names even if everything is in lower case.